# Error could not find Java SE Runtime Environment / Start from scratch

Tags: java, android, development-environment, windows-7-x64

I wanted to develop an android app a few months ago, so I followed all the steps from here-> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p and I believe I downloaded all the tools I needed. I never got around to developing anything, so I tried starting again a few days ago. When I went to the above mentioned website, it said download the new versions of this and that, so I did. I tried following the steps, but now when I try to open eclipse, I get an error saying:

> "Error could not find Java SE Runtime Environment".

My questions are:

1. How do I delete everything and start from scratch? I wan't to delete eclipse, sdk manager, sdk folder, everything. I want to follow the download instructions all over again and see what happens because it did seem to work the first time i tried a few months back.

   Do I just delete some programs from control panel?
2. If this is not easy, how can I fix the error I'm getting when trying to open eclipse?

Edit: windows 7, 64-bit OS, if that helps

Answer (score 1):

That sounds more like a problem of a corrupted Java installation. Check the JAVA_HOME environment variable. If this is empty fix this and try again.

To delete eclipse and the sdk just delete them from where you installed them.

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTIONS:

0) I assume you're running Windows.  Please specify if you're on a different platform.

1) Delete Eclipse.
   If you're not using Eclipse for anything else yet, I would strongly encourage you to *delete* it.

2) Uninstall your Java JDK (from Control Panel).

Download and install the JDK from Oracle: http://java.oracle.com.

3) Download and install the "ADT Bundle for Windows": https://developer.android.com/sdk/

In earlier versions of Android, you had to install Eclipse, the Android Plugins, and the Android SDK separately. I believe this is the procedure your link describes.

The newer "ADT Bundle" saves you this trouble.  If Android is the only thing you're using Eclipse for (at least for now), you definitely want the ADT bundle.  And you can probably ignore most of the instructions in your link.

'Hope that helps..

Comment: what do you mean 'delete' eclipse? i tried downloading it a few times so i have 4 or 5 eclipse.exe files. should i just send them to recycling bin? or uninstall from control panel?

Comment: also, i can't find ADK bundle. i see SDK and ADT.

Comment: I mean "send to the recycling bin".  Eclipse is a filecopy install: Control Panel doesn't know about it.  The Android SDK: yes, uninstall from Control panel.  Eclipse: just delete your top-level Eclipse directory.  And yes, I meant "ADT bundle".  Sorry about the typo!  Please try it, and let us know what happens.

Comment: i deleted eclipse. couldnt find android sdk in control panel. deleted all folders relating to previous download attempts. then i downloaded the zipped adt bundle, extracted it into desktop folder by following these steps...
1) Unpack the ZIP file (named adt-bundle-<os_platform>.zip) and save it to an appropriate location, such as a "Development" directory in your home directory.
2) Open the adt-bundle-<os_platform>/eclipse/ directory and launch eclipse.